# Move member function generation

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ios>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <memory>

struct value
{
    ~value() = default;
    std::unique_ptr<std::string> s;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_move_constructible<value>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_move_assignable<value>::value    << '\n';

    using str_ptr = std::unique_ptr<std::string>;
    std::cout << std::is_move_constructible<str_ptr>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_move_assignable<str_ptr>::value    << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output (compiled with g++ v4.7.2, http://ideone.com/CkW1tG):

```
false
false
true
true
```

As I expect, `value` is not move constructible and is not move assignable because:

```
~value() = default;
```

is a *user-declared* destructor, which prevents the implicit generation of move members according to section *12.8* (see below).
If the destructor is removed then `value` is move constructible and move assignable, as I expect (http://ideone.com/VcR2eq).

However, when the definition of `value` is changed to (http://ideone.com/M8LHEA):

```
struct value
{
    ~value() = default;
    std::string s;      // std::unique_ptr<> removed
};
```

the output is:

```
true
true
true
true
```

`value` is unexpectedly move constructible and move assignable.
Am I misunderstanding or is this a compiler bug?

---

*Background*: I provided an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875230/c11-magically-deleted-constructor-in-bst) question and was informed that `Tree<>` was moveable, but I am unsure and am attempting to determine for certain if it is or not.

---

Section *8.4.2 Explicitly-defaulted functions* of the c++11 standard (draft n3337):

> Explicitly-defaulted functions and implicitly-declared functions are
>   collectively called defaulted functions, and the implementation shall
>   provide implicit definitions for them (12.1 12.4, 12.8), which might mean
>   defining them as deleted.
>   A special member function is user-provided if it is user-declared and
>   not explicitly defaulted or deleted on its first declaration.
>   A user-provided explicitly-defaulted function (i.e., explicitly defaulted
>   after its first declaration) is defined at the point where it is
>   explicitly defaulted; if such a function is implicitly defined as deleted,
>   the program is ill-formed. [ Note: Declaring a function as defaulted after its
>   first declaration can provide efficient execution and concise definition while
>   enabling a stable binary interface to an evolving code base.—end note ]

Section *12.8 Copying and moving class objects* (point 9):

```
If the definition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move constructor,
one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
- X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
- X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
- X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator,
- X does not have a user-declared destructor, and
- the move constructor would not be implicitly defined as deleted.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::is_move_constructible<T>` is true iff `std::is_constructible<T, T&&>` is true, but that doesn't imply that such a construction will call a move constructor, only that it is possible to construct the type from an rvalue of the same type. Such a construction might use a copy constructor.

When `value::s` is a `unique_ptr` the type's copy constructor and copy assignment operator are defined as deleted, because the `s` member is not copyable.  It does not have a move constructor and move assignment operator because, as you pointed out, it has a user-declared destructor. That means it has no copy constructor and no move constructor (and no other user-defined constructors that could accept an argument of type `value&&`) so `std::is_constructible<value, value&&>` is false.

When `value::s` is a `string` the type's copy constructor and copy assignment operator are  **not** defined as deleted, because the `s` member **is** copyable, and so `value` is also copyable, and a CopyConstructible type is also MoveConstructible, because it's valid in this context:

```
value v1;
value v2 = std::move(v1);  // calls copy constructor
```

That means `std::is_constructible<value, value&&>` is true, even though it invokes the copy constructor not a move constructor.

Comment: +1 Thanks, very clear explanation. Out of curiousity, are you aware of any trait that checks explicitly for the presence of the move members?

Comment: There isn't one. [_"the core language semantics aren't actually very useful to a library writer; they don't care whether or not a class has something which the core language considers a copy constructor. They want to know if actually writing T(someT) will work, whether it calls a copy constructor or a move constructor or a member template constructor or whatever constructor."_](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3142.html) However, you could check `is_move_constructible<T>::value && !is_copy_constructible<T>::value`